# Flutter Table Calendar Event List Refresh

Tags: flutter

I am using the [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package for Flutter.

When I am deleting/updating events to the calendar, I always have to click again on the respective date to see the events afterward.

I want to make this happen automatically. I have not found yet a property to do so.

When adding an event the list gets updated automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

I only had to add the `setState(){}` method and within it, the deleting of the event would take place. So this is how it looks like:

```
setState(() { customEvents[_controller.selectedDay].removeAt(index);  });
```

In my case, I used a Stateful Widget as a state management "tool". By wrapping the deletion with setState, I update the state and thus the screen.