# Flutter Table Calendar Update Firestore Data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, calendar

I am using the Table Calendar package with flutter. Please note that I am using Firestore.

I am trying to figure out how to update the list of items instantly when the user adds or deletes items.  So far I need to click on the day again to see changes.  I am using setState in the onDaySelected which currently updates the data.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That requires a more complex state management than using `setState`. Check the `flutter_bloc` package for example. You also have `riverpod` and one of the most simple is `provider`. You can find a lot of information in their apis and even online.

The packages:

- [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)
- [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod)
- [proivider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

There is also a complete list of all the state management packages you can use in Flutter. [Here's](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) the official list, and you also a not official [list](https://fluttergems.dev/state-management) (however it is also valid!).

Comment: Thanks.  I am familiar with using some of the state management packages.  But I am just trying to figure out how else I can update the data for the selected day.  Right now it seems like the only way to do this is the onDaySelected parameter which updates only when a day is selected.

Comment: You could use a `BlocBuild` and building again when the items are changed. If I'm not wrong, the calendar uses a list of events. You could simply update the list as it changes.

Comment: I am most familiar with using Provider.  But with the Table Calendar Package I need to use the List<dynamic> property from the onDaySelected and set the list that should show to the List<dynamic>.  It also connected my list with what date should show.  I am trying to make something like what @Georgios made at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803872/flutter-table-calendar-event-list-refresh.